# Display specific category based on link pressed | Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a blog that renders every single category with all of their respective sub_categories on the same page. (index view) I have a nav section that I want to utilize to render only a specific subcategories' posts based on the link pressed. I don't know if this is possible with ruby alone, so I thought JQuery might be the way.

**blog_categories index.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to "BLOG", blog_path %> <!-- Will render latest posts. -->

<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    NEWS <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">All News</a></li> <!-- Will render all subcategories that belong to the "news" category -->
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Good News</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Bad News</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    REVIEWS <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">All Reviews</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Software</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<% BlogCategory.top_level.find_each do |category| %>
  <% category.sub_categories.find_each do |sub_category| %>
    <% sub_category.posts.find_each do |post| %>

      <%= link_to post do %>
        ...
      <% end %>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**The blog_categories_controller:**

```
def index
  @category = BlogCategory.find_by_id(params[:id])
  unless @category.nil? # Allows for categories to have nothing in them, eliminating the NoMethodError
    @sub_category = @category.sub_categories.first
    @posts = @subcategory.posts
  end
end


private

  def cat_params
    params.require(:blog_category).permit(:name, :parent_id, :sub_category)
  end
```

My `sub_categories` are related to main categories through a `parent_id` column in the `blog_categories` table via self-referential relation.

I've read a bit about active record querying on [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) and seen something about conditions such as `Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])` Could this be used?

If this isn't the proper way of using the HTML dropdowns to iterate through BlogCategory, I would love to know what way would be best to handle this problem, thank you!

Comment: It's 'un-Rails-y' to put a `find_each` query directly into your view. You should probably start by getting that into a single query in the controller (use joins instead of nested `find_each` to avoid n+1 issues), store it in an instance variable, and the use that instance variable in the view

Comment: @NMPennypacker Thanks, I tried to use `@categories = BlogCategory.top_level.joins(params[:id])` in my `index` method but it raised a SyntaxError. Did I pass the wrong argument through? I implemented it into my view via this code: `<% @categories do |category| %>`

Comment: The html dropdowns are what you are trying to achieve by iterating on BlogCategory ? What action does `link_to "BLOG", blog_path` trigger ?

Comment: @sovalina Oh, that just intended to link to the blogs main page (it's currently an old link pointing to the url: `/posts` instead of what I'm on right now which is `/blog_categories` I might switch it back though once I figure all of this out.

Comment: @sovalina and yes, I'm trying to use the HTML dropdowns to iterate through BlogCategory.

Comment: @Jake how do you get your `params[:id]` inside your index view ? if you want to iterate through all your blog_categories why do you want to reach one specific `@category` inside your index controller ?

Comment: @sovalina I updated my question with my `private` code. I want to iterate through every `sub_category` so I can display only one subcategory at a time (or all subcategories under a specific main category). - ex: I want to go take a look at all of the software reviews on the website, so I click on the software link under the reviews dropdown and have it isolate the posts with a `blog_category_id` of that specific category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the solution I found to work for me:**

You can link to an item in a table (in this case the blog_categories table) by using the respective `id` (or `slug` if you're using them) in a link path.

Example: The subcategory you want to link to has an `id` of "1" (or a slug of "reviews") you can link to it like so:

With ID: `<a href="/blog_category/1">Reviews</a>`

With Slug: `<a href="/blog/reviews">All Reviews</a>`

This can be done for all of the links in a dropdown:

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CATEGORIES <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- without slugs -->
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/blog_categories/1">Reviews</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/blog_categories/2">Tutorials</a></li>
    <!-- with slugs -->
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/blog/reviews">Reviews</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/blog/tutorials">Tutorials</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Basically the format of these links will be `<a href="/[table_name]/[table_item]>Link text</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code and question, it seems you want to show all the categories, their sub categories and the posts in each sub category on your index page. I am assuming you have a finite number of posts, else you might want to limit it to n (5?) number of posts per sub category. If so, you can have the following controller:

```
def index
  @categories = BlogCategory.top_level.includes(sub_categories: :posts)
end
```

Then in the view, you can easily access `@categories`, `@categories[i].sub_categories` and `@categories[i].sub_categories[j].posts` without any extra queries being triggered from the view. Something on the lines of:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <%= category.name %> <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category| %>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><%= sub_category.name %></a></li>
      <!-- And if you want to show the posts here, then loop through sub_category.posts -->
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

You can use jquery to show and hide relevant sub categories and posts depending on what the user clicks. Here's an example:
http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't want to show every category at once in any case but would want to show every subcategory of a single main category. Also, how would I make it so by default, only the 5 most recent posts of any category are displayed on the index? I'm not very familiar with jquery either, I just wasn't sure if it would be the only way to solve this.

Comment: I don't exactly get what you are trying to say here, but if you only want to show 1 category and all it's subcategories on index page, then change the controller query to `BlogCategory.find(params[:id]).includes(sub_categories: :posts)`. If you want to show all categories, but show subcategories only on clicking a category, then generate the complete view as I suggest and then use jquery to show/hide relevant elements in the HTML on category clicks.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to get something where a link like: `<li role="presentation"><a href="#">All <%= category.name %></a></li>` to display all of the posts that belong to subcategories that belong to the main category.

Comment: As for limiting results to only 5 recent posts, it probably isn't possible using a single ActiveRecord query. You'll have to iterate on all sub_categories, and query posts of each sub_category with `.limit(5)`. Having said that, that's too many queries for a single page. You probably need to make some architectural changes to your app, and probably need to cache recent 5 posts per sub_category somewhere (redis, memcached). You can then query this cache to render your index page, which should be very fast, and you'll not even need to hit the database.

Comment: I believe "main category" is the category on which the user clicked. If you want it on the same page, use jquery to show the subcategories and posts of this category and hide everything else. Look at the jquery example link I shared. If you want the user to land on a different page on that link click, then the new controller action should do the query `BlogCategory.find(params[:id]).includes(sub_categories: :posts)` and render a new view with sub_categories and posts obtained from this query.

Comment: I would like it to be on a seperate page but don't know how to apply all of this code to make it happen. I've tried to use that query and it raises this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BlogCategoriesController#index` "Couldn't find BlogCategory with 'id'="

Comment: If you want that to happen on a separate page, you'll need to have 2 actions and routes. The first page just displays the categories, and all those categories are links to the second action. The links will have the category id in the URL and clicking it will call a different action, which will query the sub_categories and posts for the category (as I suggested), and render the new view for this second action. I suggest that you read through the rails guide to get a better understanding of how a rails application and routes work. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I would also add that this same navigation system is used on each `posts.show` so it would have to link to the specific subcategory's posts based on the selection.

Comment: Probably you should explore Ajax calls as well. That way you will not need to load the menus every time (less queries). You can just load a partial with the posts on each category click.